# ASP.net validation of any invalid value

Tags: asp.net

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Calculator.aspx.cs" Inherits="Calculator" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Stats Calculator</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: powderblue;
        }

        h4 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Statistics Calculator</h1>
    <p>Enter three numbers and click the Submit button to find out the statistics</p>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="FirstNumber" runat="server" Text="First Number: " AssociatedControlID="TextBox1"></asp:Label></b>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="required1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                ID="regex1"
                ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                ValidationExpression="((\d+)((\.\d{1,2})?))$"
                ErrorMessage="Input string is not in correct format"
                Text="Input string is not in correct format"
                ForeColor="Red"
                runat="server">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <br />
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="SecondNumber" runat="server" Text="Second Number: " AssociatedControlID="TextBox2"></asp:Label></b>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="required2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                ID="regex2"
                ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                ValidationExpression="((\d+)((\.\d{1,2})?))$"
                ErrorMessage="Input is not in correct format"
                Text="Input string is not in correct format"
                ForeColor="Red"
                runat="server">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <br />
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="ThirdNumber" runat="server" Text="Third Number: " AssociatedControlID="TextBox3"></asp:Label></b>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="required3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                ID="regex3"
                ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
                ValidationExpression="((\d+)((\.\d{1,2})?))$"
                ErrorMessage="Input is not in correct format"
                Text="Input string is not in correct format"
                ForeColor="Red"
                runat="server">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" />

            <h1>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Statistics of the numbers you entered</h1>
            <h4>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <b>Maximum:</b>&nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
            <h4>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<b>Minimum:</b>&nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
            <h4>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <b>Average:</b>&nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
            <h4>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <b>Total:</b>&nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have an ASP.net form with validation, althought I would like to know how I would be able to display an error message for all fields if any of the values are not valid. What would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: You should look into a `ValidationSummary`

Comment: I did try that from before, but it just lists all the error messages in a bullet-styled list

Comment: If that does not meet your requirements, you can create your own `CustomValidator`